# Django: reverse for REST framework login route not working

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am pretty new to Django. Now I try to using Django Rest Framework.
I have my custom login template, and I want to POST my login form to the Rest Framework's login route (`/api-auth/login` by default).
In my main `urls.py` I have:

```
url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
```

So, in my template I'm trying to fetch url by namespace (`rest_framework`) and name (`login`):

```
<form id="loginForm" method="POST" action="{% url 'rest_framework:login' as login_url %}" name="loginForm">
```

But as a result I have empty action attribute in my form.
Can someone explain me, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the `as login_url` out of your `action` tag:

```
<form id="loginForm" method="POST" action="{% url 'rest_framework:login' %}" name="loginForm">
```